# How to catch Uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'datatable' of undefined. error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typeerror, typeof, adblock

When I turn off Google API I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined" message.

I would like to catch this undefined error and have a window popping up saying "Google has been disabled" but I'm not sure what typeof Object is undefined. I'm currently checking "DataTable" Object but I'm pretty sure this is wrong as the window pops up regardless now.

Here is my code.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
if(typeof DataTable == "undefined"){
window.alert("sometext");
} else {
data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');
data.addColumn('string', 'Type');
data.addColumn('string', 'Code');
data.addColumn('string', 'Aggregation');
data.addColumn('string', 'Stage');

data.addRows([
&lt;xsl:apply-templates select="/*" mode="render"/>
['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
]);

data.removeRow(data.getNumberOfRows() - 1);

drawDebugFlow(data);
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote? I thought this was a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of:

```
if(typeof DataTable == "undefined"){
```

use:

```
if(typeof google == "undefined" || typeof google.visualization == "undefined"){
```

Error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined" not "Datatable is undefined"